# How can I write constructor within an arithmetic expression?

Tags: javascript, constructor, arithmetic-expressions

I want to cut down on ugly code in JavaScript, especially relating to constructors.

I have a vector defined as:

```
function Vector2(X, Y) {
    this.x = 0.0;
    this.y = 0.0;

    if (X)
        this.y = Y;
    if (Y)
        this.y = Y;
}
```

Right now, in order to add two vectors together, I must write:

```
var vector1 = new Vector2(1.0, 0.5);
var vector2 = new Vector2(4.5, 1.0);

vector1.x += vector2.x;
vector1.y += vector2.y;
```

What I want to make the code prettier, easier to read, and make a smaller file when many constructors are used. What I want to be able to write is:

```
vector1 += vector2;
```

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could have this :

```
function Vector(X, Y) {
    this.x = X || 0.0; // yes, I simplified a bit your constructor
    this.y = Y || 0.0;
}
Vector.prototype.add = function(v) {
   this.x += v.x;
   this.y += v.y; 
}
```

And you'd just have to do

```
var vector1 = new Vector(4,4);
var vector2 = new Vector(1,3);
vector1.add(vector2);
```

Comment: This definitely accomplishes all the goals. I was hoping for something more along the lines of overloading the operator similar to the way you would in the C family.

Anyway, thank you very much for your quick answer @dystroy.

Answer (score 0):

```
vector1 += vector2;
```

I don't know what language you come from, but you can't override operators in JavaScript.